# Kops doesn't create aws autoscaling groups for cluster autoscaler addon

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I'm running kops on aws.

There is some documentation here about how to add the autoscaler to the cluster.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/tree/master/addons/cluster-autoscaler

As far as I can tell kops doesn't create its own autoscaling groups and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to create an autoscaling group that will interact with the cluster.

I can follow all the existing documentation and I will end up with this error message
`Failed to update node registry: Unable to get first autoscaling.Group for "nodes.***redacted***"`

is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks, 
Nathan

1. What `kops` version are you running? The command `kops version`, will display
   this information.
   `Version 1.8.0`
2. What Kubernetes version are you running? `kubectl version` will print the
   version if a cluster is running or provide the Kubernetes version specified as
   a `kops` flag.
   `v1.8.6`
3. What cloud provider are you using?
   `AWS`
4. What commands did you run?  What is the simplest way to reproduce this issue?
   `kubectl apply -f autoscale.yaml`
5. What happened after the commands executed?
   `Failed to update node registry: Unable to get first autoscaling.Group for "nodes.***redacted***"`

yaml file here
https://gist.github.com/nburn42/6c94336574083be610efa911e06c7ae1

Comment: `kops` does create its own autoscaling groups: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blame/master/docs/aws.md#L333.

Answer (score 0):

This is now false. Kops does create ASGs
You possibily need to configure your cluster autoscaler using either :

- autodiscover mode (using tags & IAM roles for the node running cluster autoscaler)
- manual mode (you then list the ASGs names)

c.f. https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples for a config sample